# Two .net core webapi hosted on same server in IIS out of process mode. Getting timeouts communicating to one other

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel

I have two APIs each hosted as different web application (A, B) in single IIS website on single server.
These are in OutOfProcess mode.

I want to utilize some functionality from api B in api A.
So I used HttpClient to post data to api B endpoint from api A.
This works well during development where both are hosted in IIS express.

But when I publish these to IIS, this flow does not work and it throws error (System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out).

I have tried sending get request to google.com and it works so api is able to connect to internet but not the one hosted on same site (B).